# Import data from Access (mdb) file to Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I lost my working code before I wrote to get data from .mdb file to Excel with VBA. Now, I did not find the true way to get data to excel. Here is the my code to import data;

```
Sub importAccessdata()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sQRY As String
Dim strFilePath As String

strFilePath = "D:\00 - DENEME\Deneme_Model_v0.mdb"

'Replace the ‘DatabaseFolder’ and ‘myDB.accdb’ with your DB path and DB name

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";"

sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Connectivity"
'Replace ‘tblData’ with your Access DB Table name or Query name from which you want to download the data

With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient

    .Open Source:=sQRY, ActiveConnection:=cnn, CursorType:=adOpenForwardOnly, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, Options:=adCmdText
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheet1.Range(“A1”).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing

cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I got Run-Time Error 424 when I were running to code, I got error in "Sheet1.Range(“A1”).CopyFromRecordset rs" part of code.

I just want to get data from another Software output to use in Excel easily. My .mdb file can be seen here [image]

Whats wrong I don't know. Also I have Sheet1 worksheet in my Excel file.

Comment: You have a sheet with the name `Sheet1` - but did you also make that the Code Name? The code name is not the same as the sheet name.

Comment: Try: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: and make sure you are using `"normal"` double quotes and not the `“curly”` ones like you have in your question.

Comment: Thank your for your quick response @braX Its done! I missed...

Comment: @braX Also Can I ask an another question? How can I get just data that IsCurved column equal "No"? I have to update sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Connectivity" but what is correct method.

Comment: @HakanKeskin `sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Connectivity WHERE IsCurved = False"`.